# If $x=\max(0,y+\alpha)$, how can we write $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have $x=\max(0,y+\alpha)$
so we have $x=0$ or $x=y+\alpha$.

How can we write $y$? Only as $y=x-\alpha$, or do we add $y=-\alpha$, too?

Answer (score 1):

$x=f(y)=\max(0,y+\alpha)$, $f$ is not strictly monotone so $f^{-1}$ does not exist. Therefore you can't express $y$ as a function of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $y+\alpha\ge 0$, then $x=y+\alpha$ and $y=x-\alpha$.

If, however, $y+\alpha<0$, then $x=0$ and it is impossible from that information to deduce $y$. All you can say is that $y<-\alpha$, but there are many such $y$'s and all of them will produce the same $x$.

Comment: In some equations I replace the value of x one time by o and one time by y+α . If I have to replace the value of y in some equations. should I take both values of y?  Ps: y+α must be positive.

Comment: @Abla I understood your question to be about how you can get $y$ "back", knowing $x=\max(0,y+\alpha)$. If that was not your question, then can you please clarify your question?

Comment: This is exactly the question. Should I take both values of y and replace or only the value x-α is sufficient? The values are: y=-α or y=x-α